# Выбрать значение в зависимости от выбранного элемента в выпадающем списке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div class="zena">
 <div class="param">
   <p class="opisanie">параметр 1</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   <p class="price">1000 руб.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="param">
   <p class="opisanie">параметр 2</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   <p>1200 руб.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Имеется код показанный выше, можете подсказать (дать ссылок где посмотреть, если имеется возможность показать пример), как сделать выпадающий списком по формату

```
<список>
<парам_1>Параметр 1</парам_1>
<парам_2>Параметр 2</парам_2>
</список>
```

и если выбран Параметр 1 то вывести значение 1000 руб., а если выбран Параметр 2, то вывести значение 1200 руб.

Заранее спасибо

**добавление из комментариев:**
правильно ли я понимаю, что данные в option и value надо заполнять вручную?

```html
<div class="block_product">
 <div class="zena">
  <div class="param">
  <p class="opisanie">параметр 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <p class="price">1000 руб.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="param">
  <p class="opisanie">параметр 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <p>1200 руб.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="block_product">
 <div class="zena">
  <div class="param">
  <p class="opisanie">параметр 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <p class="price">2940 руб.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="param">
  <p class="opisanie">параметр 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <p>3040 руб.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

с помощью вот таких конструкций у меня в переменную передаются данные в форму связи

```js
var price = form.find('p.price').text();
```

я пытаюсь добавить выпадающий список как писал в письме вопроса. но у каждого блока (товара) свои параметры и цены.

**Дополнительное уточнение от 22.11.2019 13:06**

```css
function oneClickty(form) {
 var ht_3 =
  '<select id="mySelect"></select>';
 console.log(ht_3);

 var opisanie = document.getElementsByClassName("opisanie");
 console.log(opisanie);
 var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
 console.log(price);
 var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
 for(var i = 0; i < opisanie.length; i++){
  console.log(i);
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  console.log(opt);
  opt.value = price[i].innerHTML;
  console.log(opt.value);
  opt.innerHTML = opisanie[i].innerHTML; 
  console.log(opt.innerHTML);
  //select.appendChild(opt);
 };
return false;
}
```

в логе выдает следующие http://joxi.ru/823oM54f9VWwl2, но если убрать коменты с `select.appendChild(opt);`
выдает сообщение об ошибке: http://joxi.ru/L21oqRlfRP4LDr
можете подсказать в чем ошибка?

**Дополнительное уточнение от 22.11.2019 15:07**

```html
<div class="zena">
  <div class="param">
    <p class="opisanie">Параметр 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p class="price">2940 руб.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="param">
    <p class="opisanie">Параметр 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p class="price">3040 руб.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function onety(form) {
  var opisanie = document.getElementsByClassName("opisanie");
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  for (var i = 0; i < opisanie.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = price[i].innerHTML;
    opt.innerHTML = opisanie[i].innerHTML;
    select.appendChild(opt);
  };
  var drop_list = select.innerHTML;

  var
    hth = '<select id="mySelect">' + drop_list + '</select>';
  hth += '<br />';
  hth += '<br />';
  hth += '<input class="current_price" readonly value="' + 'значение price от выбранного параметра' + '">';

  console.log(hth);

  return false;
}
```

в логе формируется:

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="2940 руб.">Параметр 1</option>
  <option value="3040 руб.">Параметр 2</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input class="current_price" readonly value="значение price от выбранного параметра">
```

**Дополнительное уточнение от 26.11.2019 11:30**

Wolframm, Добавил еще несколько блоков (для наглядности примера)
(ссылка: https://codepen.io/xoyig/pen/rNNgqNj)
При такой реализации как Вы предложили в выпадающий список попадают данные из всех имеющихся на странице блоков, а не из определенного который выбран.

Также немного переработал свой пример (добавил несколько блоков):
(на примере не реализовывал всплытие блока с модальном окне и кнопку закрытия)
(ссылка: https://codepen.io/xoyig/pen/mddYGoG)
При нажатии на кнопку "Выбрать", берутся данные только из определенного блока где находится кнопка.
Не могу понять как сделать при такой реализации выпадающий список, и выбор значения в зависимости от выбранного параметра.

Comment: Выбран параметр имеется в виду по клику? Изначально видны только div "param"? Выпадающий список select? Куда выводиться значение? Уточните вопрос

Comment: Выбран параметр имеется в виду по клику?
(пример выпадающего списка: http://joxi.ru/krDMWx4tK8YZgm), ну получается, что по клику
Изначально видны только div "param"?
Да
Выпадающий список select?
Да
Куда выводиться значение?
простите не дописал вывести значение нужно в <input value="записать_значение">

Comment: Выбрать можно после наведения, после клика, после изменения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш HTML (плюс Jquery для событий):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="zena">
    <div class="rbt param">
        <p class="opisanie">Параметр 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p class="price">2940 руб.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sbt param">
        <p class="opisanie">Параметр 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p class="price">3040 руб.</p>
    </div>
  <select id="select"></select>
</div>
<input id="test"></input>

</body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // тут инициализируем опции селекта
      initializeSelect();
      // тут вешаем событие на изменение селекта
      $('#select').on('change',function(){
        // получаем значение из выбранного селекта
        var optionsValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        // добавляем выбранное значение в input
        $('#test').val(optionsValue);
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Инициализация селекта:

```
 function initializeSelect() {
  // проходим по циклу используя количество элементов описания
  for(var i = 0; i < $(".opisanie").length; i++) {
    // создаем элемент списка
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    // в качестве значения добавляем цену
    opt.value = $(".price")[i].innerHTML;
    // в качестве текста добавляем описание
    opt.text = $(".opisanie")[i].innerHTML; 
    // добавляем опцию к селекту
    $("#select").append(opt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что это: opisanie.length == price.length означает что колличетсво параметров должно равняется колличеству цен?

Comment: Добры день, @Wolframm.
можете подсказать из может возникать ошибка в `select.appendChild(opt);`
изменил вопрос тег _Дополнительное уточнение от 22.11.2019 13:06_

Comment: сейчас попробую, спасибо @Wolframm.

Comment: добавил в вопрос уточнение: _Дополнительное уточнение от 22.11.2019 15:07)_, можете еще подсказать как создать выпадающий список в форме я разобрался, а как в `input-->value` передать значение из `option-->value`. Пробовал прикрутить Вашу JS обработка события, но как то у меня не выходит.

Comment: а как это сделать? это галочка возле поста?

Comment: спасибо, на будущее буду знать.

Comment: изменил, но в логе выдало ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (структура кода как в: _Дополнительное уточнение от 22.11.2019 15:07_ + дописал `onchange="myFunction()` в select), предполагаю, что ошибка как-то похожа на предыдущую, что элемент еще не существует, но не пойму как исправить.

пробовал на codepen . io, работает, но если заменить getElementById("demo"), на getElementsByClassName("demo"), перестает. (у меня у input не id, а class)

Comment: опечатка classNsme[0]? ClassName[0]?

тестовый сохранил (https://codepen.io/xoyig/pen/xxxerbo?&editable=true#anon-signup)

но на реально проекте ошибка даже с id

Comment: набросал похожий пример: https://codepen.io/xoyig/pen/mddgwQB, как у меня в оригинале.

Comment: не совсем пойму получается, что `var htlog =` надо вынести в отдельную функцию, если Вам не сложно могли бы показать на примере?

Comment: Изменил ответ на рабочий пример

Comment: Спасибо, на выходных не будет возможности посмотреть, протестирую в понедельник

Comment: протестировал предложенный Вами пример, добавил уточнения в тело вопроса _Дополнительное уточнение от 26.11.2019 11:30_  
пробовал интерпретировать предложенный Вами код в свой вариант, но как то не вышло, могли бы подсказать, куда копать, что-бы добиться решения 
при котором при нажатии на кнопку "Выбрать" в блоке, данные выводились в отдельный блок (в моем примере это `<div id="test"></div>`), где будет выпадающий список и поле input для вывода значения в зависимости от выбранного параметра (в параметр value).  
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы за Вас тут всю программу написали. Ресурс не для этого

Comment: не хочу (есть желание самому разобраться), намекните в какую сторону двигаться.
я так понимаю основная проблема моей версии, то что элементов куда требуется вывести данные еще не существует. а как задать последовательность не очень-то пойму.

Comment: Все ответы на Ваши вопросы гуглятся по первой ссылке. Ну ничего ж ведь сложного. Уже дали все советы, бери и развивай.

Comment: >Уже дали все советы, бери и развивай. Все легко когда хорошо разбираешься в этом. Попробовал поискать в гугл по Вашему совету но не нашел. (если честно даже не знаю что искать). Могли-бы дать ссылки или подказать, что искать, что помогло-бы мне в решении проблемы.

Comment: вроде как получилось добиться того, что хотелось мне (https://codepen.io/xoyig/pen/mddYGoG).
Могли-бы подсказать или дать ссылку где можно посмотреть какие атрибуты помогут реализовать:
что-бы по умолчанию значение в вып. списке было пустое, но когда раскрывался вып. список пустого значения не было.

(Сейчас получается если нажать на кнопку "Выбрать" появляется вып. список и уже показывает 1 значение, но input пуст и что-бы выбрать 1 значение и заполнился input, вначале надо переключиться на любое другое, а потом снова на 1).

Comment: При формировании списка, добавьте первым туда option с текстом "-- выберите значение --" и атрибутом disabled = true

Comment: добавил (он появился в вып. списке), но почему то все равно в вып. списке первое значение, а не "-- выберите значение --".?
---------------
нашел решение, добавил selected, класс и скрыл через css

Answer (score 0):

если вам нужен именно выпадающий список то можно воспользоваться элементом `select`.

Простейший скрипт:

```js
const price = document.getElementById('price')
price.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  document.querySelector(".price_label").textContent = price[price.options.selectedIndex].value
})
```

```html
<select name="" id="price">
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="4000">4000</option>
  <option value="5000">5000</option>
</select>
<label class="price_label"></label>
```

Comment: в Вашем примере получается, что значение берутся из value, а как передать в значение value данные из `class="price"`, а в option данные из `class="opisanie"`
_так как по параметрам и цене, у разные товаров разные, по Вашему примеру получается что каждый раз нужно создавать новый  список_

Comment: @Boger, опишите ваш вопрос более внятно, тому что из вашего коментария ничего не понятно

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю:
У Вас список строится по: `<option>Параметр_выпадающего_списка</option>`
в
`value="значение_для_каждого_пункта_выпадающего_списка"`
но у меня получается, что значения (параметры, цена) для каждого блока свои, они записаны в классах: opisanie, price
Можно ли как-то передать эти значения в option, value
Постарался объяснить если, что уточняйте

Comment: в тексте `option` - параметр 1 и тд, в `value` цена... или вам нужно в коде найти ети все пункти и на лету создать дроп-даун с етими значениями ?)

Comment: @Boger можно сделать, например аяксом получать данные и на основе их строить селекты

Comment: `весь код в коментарий не помещаеться`, о ужас !!! Редактируйте вопрос, ету дичь в коментах никто читать не хочет.

Comment: подскажите а как?
не нахожу кнопки изменить вопрос.

Comment: прямо под вопросом кнопка "править"